# scrollTop alternative to use with tbody?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to scroll the tbody to the bottom every time I dynamically add a new row.

I have an html table but only the tbody scrolls. Unfortunately, scrollTop isn't a property of the tbody so I can't do this:

```
document.querySelector('#myTable > tbody').scrollTop = 100000;
```

And I don't want to set focus when I add a new row to the table. So, how can I get the tbody to scroll to the bottom when I add a new row?

And I don't want to use...

```
scrollIntoView(true/false)
```

...because it shifts left in IE.

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: Just an idea, you could try to grab the x/y coordinates of whatever elements you want and use them with `window.scrollTo(x,y)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it: var pos = newRow.getBoundingClientRect();
  window.scrollTo(pos.x, pos.y); --- but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
var offset = newRow.offsetTop;
newRow.parentNode.scrollTop = offset;
```

I was wrong when I said that you can't set the scrollTop of a tbody. I guess I just couldn't do it the way I tried above.